# Number in Javascript changes after declaring it as a variable. Even parsing it from a string returns a wrong number

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer, numbers

This is very weird please check it yourself.

Whenever I try to declare variable with the number 76561198322368902 it always changes to 76561198322368900 no matter what.
[Chrome Devtools Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U7sA.png)

Even when I pass the variable as a string and later parse to a number, it always changes to 76561198322368900.

I really don't know what to do. I never thought Integers were capable of such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)" in JavaScript is 9007199254740991 - trying to use the number type beyond this can yield unpredictable results.

Use the [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type if you need a bigger number.

Answer (score 1):

You just exeeded the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).